# Segmentation fault with malloc on char* in struct

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm teaching myself C and for fun I thought it would be cool to write a small web framework. The code I'm working on at the moment is for registering routes/handlers.

I've run into a segmentation fault with `malloc`, but strangely only on the fourth time it is called. I've marked the point in the code where the segmentation fault occurs. I'm not sure how to debug it other than wrapping areas of the code with `printf`s and `puts`s. I've tried using valgrind to debug this, but the segmentation fault doesn't actually happen when I run valgrind. Valgrind *does* tell me that there is a memory leak stemming from the same `malloc`, though. So obviously I'm doing something wrong there, but I don't know what.

FYI, `destroy_routes` is called just before the child process is terminated.

```
struct route {
    char *path;
    enum method method;
    int(*handler)(struct request *, int sock);
    struct route *next;
};


static struct route *routes;

void
register_route(char *path, enum method method,
               int(*handler)(struct request *, int))
{
    struct route *route;

    if (routes == NULL)
        routes = route = malloc(sizeof(struct route));
    else {
        route = routes;
        while (route->next)
            route = route->next;

        route->next = malloc(sizeof(struct route));
        route = route->next;
    }

    route->path = malloc((strlen(path) + 1) * sizeof(char)); /* <== HERE is where the segmentation fault occurs only on the fourth time */
    strcpy(route->path, path);

    route->method = method;
    route->handler = handler;

    printf("route created: %s, %i, %p\n", route->path, route->method, (void *)route->handler);
}

void
destroy_routes()
{
    struct route *prev;
    int i = 0;
    while (routes) {
        free(routes->path);
        prev = routes;
        routes = routes->next;
        free(prev);
        i++;
    }
    printf("destroyed %i routes\n", i);
}

void
register_routes()
{
    register_route("/post", GET, &do_something);
    register_route("/post", POST, &do_something_else);
    register_route("/post/:id", GET, &do_something);
    register_route("/post/:id/children", POST, &do_something_else);
}
```

Comment: `routes = route = malloc(sizeof(struct route));` : routes set first time. routes->next is not initialize.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it is in the `else` the second time around or have I been staring at this too long?

Comment: @tjb1982 `malloc` does not zero the memory, so you need to set the `next` of the last node in the linked list to NULL. You didn't do that anywhere.

Comment: you need to initialize the members required when you create a `struct route` by `malloc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed to set the `next` pointer to NULL. That could be the issue.

```
route->method = method;
route->handler = handler;
route->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. But I don't really understand why. Can you explain it?

Comment: Accessing an invalid pointer is undefined behavior. Because of not setting the next to NULL, traversing the list starting from the second invocation of `register_route` is undefined.